# Pen drive not showing any data but it shows that much space allocated. in cmd dir also not showing files

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

Pen drive not showing any data but it shows that much space allocated.

In a `cmd` shell `dir` is also not showing files.

I tried

```
-h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

But its not working:

> ''-h'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Those are arguments to `attrib`. So you should be running `attrib  -h -r -s /s /d g:*.*`

Comment: Great. I posted the above as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Pen drive not showing any data

> I tried `-h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*` but its not working:
>
> ''-h'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

`-h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*` are arguments to the [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) command, so your command should be as follows:

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

This will unhide the files on your Pen drive.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) - Display or change file attributes.